# integral problem - what is the quickest solution?

Tags: calculus, integration

I am solving the below integral.

$$\int_{0}^{1} (e^{\frac{-x}{a}}-a(1-e^{-\frac{1}{a}}))^2 dx$$

I can decompose the integrand to the simple elements doing all the algebra and then split and calculate all the integrals separately but this seems to be a very awkward way prone to mistakes.

Do you see any simpler way to solve it?

for a=2 I expect to get 0.0128

Comment: could you show what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why one would not calculate the integral directly, without substitutions. Let $c=a(1-e^{-1/a})$. Then your integral equals
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^1 (e^{-x/a}-c)^2\,dx&=\int_0^1 e^{-2x/a}-2ce^{-x/a}+c^2\,dx\\
&=\Bigl[-\frac{a}{2}e^{-2x/a}+2cae^{-x/a}\Bigr]_0^1+c^2\\
&=-\frac{a}{2}e^{-2/a}+2cae^{-1/a}+\frac{a}{2}-2ca+c^2.
\end{aligned}
$$
If you want you can insert the expression for $c$ back again. When I do that, I get

> $$-ae^{-2/a}\Bigl(a+\frac12\Bigr)+2a^2e^{-1/a}+\frac{a}{2}-a^2.$$

Inserting $a=2.0$, we indeed get something like $0.0128$.

Answer (score 1):

Putting $k = a(1-e^{-\frac{1}{a}})$, since 
$$\frac{d}{dx} (e^{\frac{-x}{a}}) = e^{\frac{-x}{a}} \left(-\frac{1}{a}\right) $$

then putting $u=e^{\frac{-x}{a}}$ we have

$$\int_{1}^{e^{-\frac{1}{a}}} (-a) (u-k)^2 (u)^{-1} du = -a \int_1^{e^{-\frac{1}{a}}} u - 2k + \frac{k^2}{u} \; \; du$$

Comment: there is something wrong, for a=2 I expect to get about 0.0128 but I don't get it

Comment: Edited. Sorry!!

Comment: I made a typo in the initial equation, a minus was missing, let me check now

Comment: that just changes the value of $k$

Comment: for a=2  the upper limit doesn't make sense  exp(-0.5)<1

Comment: $= -a \int (u - 2k + \frac{k^2}{u}) du = -a(0.5u^2-2ku+k^2 ln|u|)$ 
<br> now substituing back the k and u, I get <br>
$-a(0.5e^{\frac{-2x}{a}}-2a(1-e^{\frac{-1}{a}})e^{\frac{-x}{a}} +a^2(1-2e^{\frac{-1}{a}}+e^{\frac{-2}{a}})*(ln|e^{\frac{-x}{a}}|))|_0^1=-a[0.5e^{\frac{-2}{a}}-2a(1-e^{\frac{-1}{a}})(e^{\frac{-1}{a}})+a^2(1-2e^{\frac{-1}{a}}+e^{\frac{-2}{a}})(\frac{1}{a})-0.5+a(1-e^{\frac{-1}{a}})]$ <br> substituting a=2 I don't get the expected value 0.0128 where I did a mistake?

Comment: Computing the final form with WolframAlpha gives the correct result, check your calculations maybe...?
http://goo.gl/8DcpFg